# Python timezone to region converter

Tags: python, timezone, region, pytz

Is there any way to convert all the timzones of pytz's all_timezones_set to their specific region i,e 'Asia', 'America', 'Europe' etc.

At first I thought the first part of the timezones are the specific region. But then after viewing result for my custom converter I realised some timezones start with Etc, some even doesn't have two parts separated by slash. This is the code snippet. The result is obviously incorrect. So, I tried finding ways to convert them but couldn't find any

```
def parse_region_from_timezone(timezone):
    if timezone.find('/') != -1:
        return timezone[:timezone.find('/')]
    return timezone
```

Comment: you could check against a set of "valid" regions. btw. with Python 3.9 use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), e.g. `regions = {parse_region_from_timezone(z) for z in zoneinfo.available_timezones()}`

Comment: But in that case I have to build a complete list of timezone to regions map which I tried but couldn't find any data available online. Like for many timezones I don't even know which region it belongs to. And there's around 592 timezones which is why its harder to find region for individual timezones

Comment: I'm not sure actually if I understand your problem. What do you mean by "region"? I mean, "America" is a region, but also "South-West Texas"...

Comment: By region I meant america. Basically, I am trying to map every times to a region (e,g, America, Europe, Asia, Africa, Antarctica, Australia etc)

Comment: map every timezones to a region*

Comment: if you run the code snippet from my first comment, you get a set of like 60 entries. It shouldn't be too difficult to clean that up to get a "validation table". Not sure if that is the most clever or comprehensive  thing, but at least pretty obvious what's going on ;-)

Comment: Ohh...That's possible. I can use to parse function to map each timezone to a region and can assign each region an average timezone. Actually that does solve the problem as I don't care about the region name. I just need regionwise grouped timezone for my usecase